# how to replace value in column based on condition

Tags: dataframe, replace, conditional-statements

dataset:

```
cust no acc no  schme code  product code
0   102283447   809002316863    swmse   rbl finserve
1   102283447   809002661291    ecltl   ecl
2   101124069   809001215907    aksme   akshada
3   101124069   809001211305    aksme   akshada
4   101124069   8090012837146   ecltl   ecl
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if ((data['cust no'].duplicated()==True).any() and (data['product code']!='rbl finserve').any()):
    data['new']=='other bc acc'
else:
    data['new']==data['schme code']


data['new']=np.nan
for i in data['product code']:
    if i!='rbl finserve':
        if (data['schme code']=='ecltl').any():
            data['new']=='other ecl bc'
        else: 
            data['new']=data['schme code']
```

I want to change schme code if the accounts are more than two. for those accounts which gave 1st account product as rbl finserve then dont change but if other than 'rbl finserve' then change schme code from 'ecltl' to 'other ecltl bc'

Answer (score 0):

```
cust no acc no  schme code  product code
0   102283447   809002316863    swmse   rbl finserve
1   102283447   809002661291    ecltl   ecl
2   101124069   809001215907    aksme   akshada
3   101124069   809001211305    aksme   akshada
4   101124069   8090012837146   ecltl   ecl
```